# Test Posting to Facebook Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing my first "Facebook-App". What I want is to send postings from my Java application to a Facebook page.

I followed the Facebook developer guide. And for now I have the App and some testusers. With the testuser I want to try posting things to my tespage.

So I used Postman to create a POST-Request described at (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing).

As Response I get

```
    {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \\\n          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both manage_pages \\\n          and publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, \\\n          requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with \\\n          sufficient administrative permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "AF_g89q8Af14WLdij2_2mkW"
  }
}
```

The Dev-Site said that I need to give the app into review to gain this permissions. But how should I make a screencast how the app is working when I can't post to my page?

Do you have any idea how to get this solved?

Thanks in advance 
Dominic

Comment: You can not post to pages as a normal user any more; you can only post _as_ the page, and for that you need a page access token, as the error message explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe mention posting as User to a Page isn't allowed any more.

My fault was, I thought the access_token I used was a page access token. But it wasn't. After generating a page access token and using this all works fine.